# Thunar fails to reconnect broken ssh connection?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, ssh, thunar

When I open an sftp connection to a server with Thunar, and this connection is broken for some reason (either the server kills it because of inactivity, or the connection is lost), then when I try to reconnect to the same server, Thunar just hangs. I am forced to quit Thunar, and then when I start it again and try to reconnect, it still hangs. The only thing that works is logging out/logging back again into my Xubuntu session, and then trying to reconnect.

I can't really give any technical details that would allow you to reproduce this bug. If you help me to diagnose it I can give more details, as requested.

What can I do to solve this problem? Are similar bugs reported?
Is there a better way to "restart" the session, without having to log off/on (maybe there is a service I can restart)?

Answer (score 0):

Old one but bug's still out there.

As a workaround, what I do is kill ssh processes linked with the lost server. When I relaunch Thunar, it's working again

```
ps -ef | grep ssh | grep server-name-or-ip
```

Then

```
kill -9 process'-id
```